# Magento 2 404 error admin panel

Tags: http-status-code-404, admin, magento2

Recently I installed Magento ver 2.0

After successfull installation, I tried to login to admin panel but it say 404 not found.

I am really not getting what is causing such issue. Moreover from the URL it can seen that I am logged into admin oanel but the dashboards is not visible.

[URL:](http://example.com/magento-2/index.php/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/9413917f383b1e505ea5d4cb3b79f61e/)

Can anyone shed some light on this ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  I had to enable the `mod_rewrite` module and set the `AllowOverride` to `all` for `/var/www/html` directory in the apache configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a known issue?  Some info regarding a work around currently as well.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/254

According to that, this may fix it:

Quick fix:
in app/code/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db.php:64
paste following

```
if($extName == 0) {
  continue;
}
```

after

```
foreach ($extensions as $extName) {
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is in getting of REQUEST_URI environment variable value and checking it withSCRIPT_FILENAME and SCRIPT_NAME environment variables values.

So a cause of the problem is in adding of /index.php/ prefix to the request path and the Magento url generation has this value hardcoded for admin.

Override method called _updatePathUseRewrites in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Mode/store.php file :
Replace this Function:

```
protected function _updatePathUseRewrites($url)
{
if ($this->isAdmin()    || !$this->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_USE_REWRITES) || !Mage::isInstalled()) {
$url .= basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/';        }
return $url;
}
```

with

```
    protected function _updatePathUseRewrites($url)
{
if ($this->isAdmin()    || !$this->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_USE_REWRITES) || !Mage::isInstalled()) {
$url .= '/';        }
return $url;
}
```

This will definitely solve your Problem

Comment: That is not a Magento 2 file.

Comment: @Modulesoft haven't you closed till now?