# Magento 404 Admin Page Login

Tags: magento

I am getting a 404 error when trying to go to my admin page was working fine earlier today. Haven't changed anything since I last logged in and the only thing I was doing was assigning products to categories.

http://mytempsite.net/gotie/admin

**WHAT IVE TRIED SO FAR**

Delete the following file:-

app/etc/use_cache.ser <-- **I could not find the file in ftp or ssh**

then tried doing this
 Opened PhpMyAdmin
- Went to my database
- Clicked SQL
- Ran the following SQL Query:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Comment: try http://mytempsite.net/gotie/index.php/admin depending on your server configuration this might work

Comment: tried it and didn't work. Not a noob :)

Comment: Solution to this topic found here

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409710/magento-2-404-error-admin-panel][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409710/magento-2-404-error-admin-panel

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about logging in to your admin console, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in getting of REQUEST_URI environment variable value and checking it withSCRIPT_FILENAME and SCRIPT_NAME environment variables values.

So a cause of the problem is in adding of /index.php/ prefix to the request path and the Magento url generation has this value hardcoded for admin.

Override method called _updatePathUseRewrites in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Mode/store.php file : Replace this Function:

```
protected function _updatePathUseRewrites($url)
{
if ($this->isAdmin()    || !$this->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_USE_REWRITES) || !Mage::isInstalled()) {
$url .= basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/';        }
return $url;
}
```

with

```
    protected function _updatePathUseRewrites($url)
{
if ($this->isAdmin()    || !$this->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_USE_REWRITES) || !Mage::isInstalled()) {
$url .= '/';        }
return $url;
}
```

This will definitely solve your Problem

Comment: Instead of modifying core files, why not suggest copying the file to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Mode/store.php` then applying the patch?  This way the file will not be overwritten with upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete your .htaccess file in root of your website?

Comment: No I did not, i tried replacing it (after this happened) with a new one but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache. Delete all files in var/cache/.

Also clear your browser's cache.

Comment: That should be a given i already tried that....